# VisualSVN server backup

Tags: svn, backup, visualsvn-server

I am working on C#.Net product. I am using VisualSVN source control server. I want to take sourcecode backup on every week from VisualSVN server. I don't have any idea taking backup.

thanks

Comment: VisualSVN Server offers a [built-in backup solution with scheduling and verification](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/backup/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this question on StackOverflow:  https://serverfault.com/questions/20514/what-ways-there-are-to-backup-repositories-for-windows-visualsvn/20616#20616

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.